# Calculate reservoir volume after rain falls

Tags: python

I want to get better at commenting

```
# The current volume of a water reservoir (in cubic metres)
reservoir_volume = 4.445e8
# The amount of rainfall from a storm (in cubic meters)
rainfall = 5e6

# decrease the rainfall variable by 10% to account for runoff

rainfall -= (rainfall * 10/100) # First, you want to calculate 
# how much of 10% of the 'rainfall' variable, then you subtract that
# from the actual value of the 'rainfall' variable. Finally, assign 
# that value as the new value for the 'rainfall' variable.


# add the rainfall variable to the reservoir_volume variable

reservoir_volume += rainfall # Add both the 'reservoir_volume' 
# variable and the 'rainfall' variable and then assign that to the 
# 'reservoir_volume' variable as its new value


# increase reservoir_volume by 5% to account for stormwater that
# flows into the reservoir in the days following the storm

reservoir_volume += (reservoir_volume * (5 / 100)) #First, you calculate        
# how much 5% of the value from the 'reservoir_volume' variable is. Then,
# you add that value to 'reservoir_volume' from the previous line and 
# assign that new value to the 'reservoir_volume' variable 


# decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation

reservoir_volume -= reservoir_volume * (5 / 100)
# we get the value of the 'reservoir_volume' from the previous line, 
# then we multiply 5% to get the amount of water that got evaporated. 
# After that, we subtract that water that got evaporated from the value of the 
# 'reservoir_volume' variable. Finally, assign that new value for
# 'reservoir_volume' variable.


# subtract 2.5e5 cubic metres from reservoir_volume to account for water that's piped to arid regions.

reservoir_volume -= 2.5e5 #subtract 2.5e5 cubic metres from reservoir_volume to 
# account for water that's piped to arid regions. After that, assign that 
# value to be the new value for the 'reservoir_volume' variable.


# print the new value of the reservoir_volume variable

print(reservoir_volume) # Going through that computation, we should get a value a float of 447627500.0
```

Comment: some of your code is getting formatted as regular text because you didn't use backticks. I tried fixing it for you but it says you have too much code and to add more details.

Comment: Additionally, I would refrain from commenting things that are plainly obvious (eg `i += 5 #add 5 to i`). in general, if someone reading the code for the first time would have no questions, you don't need a comment.

Comment: Comments should describe *why* your code is doing what it does, not *what* it does. Comments like `# add the rainfall variable to the reservoir_volume variable` are useless because they don't tell me why you want to add these two variables.

Comment: I tried editing my code, but it would submit my edited code. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your question is important because code writing is a form of technical
writing**. Few software engineers view their craft explicitly in these terms,
and most software education focuses overwhelmingly on algorithms and data
structures, leaving effective technical writing as a kind of afterthought --
presumably as something that students will figure out through hard-earned
experience.

**Comments are very useful**. Contrary to the claims of some black-and-white
thinkers in our field -- who make claims like "the code should speak for
itself" or "comments are a code smell" -- comments are a vital tool in your
arsenal. Ignore anyone who says you shouldn't be writing comments at all.
Well-designed comments can enhance code readability in substantial ways.

**But code is more important than comments**. Even though comments are powerful
and vital, they are of secondary importance. The code matters most. The job of
comments is to enhance and clarify, not dominate. Your current comments invert
that relationship: the comments are so expansive that they undermine
readability. The trick is to find an effective balance.

**Prefer named constants over explained values**. Your current
code has magic values scattered throughout. When you do that you increase
the perceived need to elaborate on their meaning. A more effective strategy
is to give those values meaningful labels, in the form of constant names.

```
# Reservoir, rainfall, and irrigation volumes (cubic metres).
INITIAL_VOLUME = 4.445e8
RAINFALL = 5e6
IRRIGATION = 2.5e5

# Proportions of:
# - Rain diverted to runoff.
# - Reservoir increased by stormwater.
# - Reservoir decreased by evaporation.
RUNOFF_RATIO = 0.1
STORMWATER_RATIO = 0.05
EVAPORATION_RATIO = 0.05
```

**Organize code in commented paragraphs**. As illustrated above, if you group
related lines of code together -- and give the entities meaningful names -- you
can often achieve quite effective commenting in very few words. Each chunk of
code is an organized unit (a "paragraph") with a leading comment that tries to
convey the essential purpose of the code and to clarify any details that are
not already obvious from the code. The comments also play an important role in
allowing subsequent readers to scan the code very quickly, "speed-reading" the
code by quickly scanning the comments until they find the paragraph of
immediate concern.

**Organize documents to aid navigation and readability**. That organizational principle can be generalized to many
other forms of technical communication, such as sending
email or writing code reviews: organize the content so that
it's easy for the reader to navigate the document, skim
quickly, or even skip sections. Case in
point: most of my reviews on this website rely on a
similar technique, with bolded headlines attempting to announce
or summarize the key point of each paragraph.

**In nearly all cases, put comments on their own lines**. Comments
tacked on the end of code lines are usually less flexible and
require more ongoing maintenance as the code evolves over time
(there are exceptions to this rule, but they are fairly rare).
The ratio comments above are a good example: even though one
might be tempted to write these as line-trailing comments,
I usually find that readability and maintainability are better
when the comments sit at the top of each paragraph, on their own
lines.

**With good organization and naming, the algorithm itself often needs little
explanation**. The comment shown here does not add a lot of substance, but
that's OK. In this case, the comment mostly plays
two roles: (1) it reinforces the overall purpose
(computing volume after it rains); and (2) it supports
organizational goals by
maintaining the overall symmetry of a
document structured as commented paragraphs.

```
# Compute reservoir volume after a rain event.
reservoir = INITIAL_VOLUME + RAINFALL * (1 - RUNOFF_RATIO)
reservoir += reservoir * STORMWATER_RATIO
reservoir -= reservoir * EVAPORATION_RATIO
reservoir -= IRRIGATION
print(reservoir)
```

**Next steps**. Start putting your code in functions. And consider
using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to parameterize the script rather than hardcoding all
of the values and ratios.